Add Microsoft account login in Laravel application
I currently have a web application made with Laravel, which already has the standard login system provided by Laravel.
I would like to add the option of being able to log into the application also through a Microsoft 365 account, for those users who have it.
I have been searching in Google and I have found some interesting pages where it is explained how to log in with a Microsoft account (with Microsoft Graph), like for example the following one:
https://dcblog.dev/login-with-microsoft-graph
However, in this tutorial (and in all the others I have found), they propose a login exclusively through the Microsoft account (unless I am wrong).
What I need is not to replace the current login in the application with a Microsoft login, but to add this second option and allow the user to log in both ways.
My doubt is because the problem I see is that in the tutorials I have seen, a migration of the user table is created from scratch, when in my case I already have a users table. I don't know how I should act in this sense, since (I think) at first I don't think it is necessary to have another user table for logging into the application, but simply send the necessary parameters (tenant, client_id, client_secret,...) to Microsoft and get a success/error response.
Please, I would appreciate some help in this regard in order to move forward, as I am completely stuck and cannot find a solution.
Thank you very much in advance.

Install Laravel Socialite and Microsoft Provider:
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/socialite
https://packagist.org/packages/socialiteproviders/microsoft

By using composer:
composer require laravel/socialite
composer require socialiteproviders/microsoft

Create two columns migrations for the users table:
'microsoft_id',   
'microsoft_token' 

Add  the Routings and define the function in the AuthController:
Route::get('auth/microsoft', [AuthController::class, 'redirectToMicrosoft'])->name('microsoft.login');
Route::get('auth/microsoft/callback', [AuthController::class, 'handleMicrosoftCallback']);

Env configurations:
MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID=your_client_id
MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET=your_secret
MICROSOFT_REDIRECT_URI=http://your-app.com/auth/microsoft/callback
MICROSOFT_TENANT_ID=common

Configure and check use case for both libraries as per the reference link. It will be helpful for you.

Thanks a lot for the help. Works perfect.

You are welcome @OmarMohamed :)

You could try to use laravel-socialite:
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/socialite
Together with a provider for Microsoft:
https://socialiteproviders.com/Microsoft
